# Change center point of Object3D in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am dynamically adding meshes to an `Object3D` and was wondering if it was possible to get the center of the object such that I can do rotations and on translations equally on the whole mesh and not 'centered' on one end. I know you can access the geometry property of `Mesh` but I couldn't find an equivalent for `Object3D`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use box3.setFromObject(Object3D) to figure out the bounding box of your object and from that the center of your object3D. Take a look at [Threejs: computing the bounding box of rotated text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646945/threejs-computing-the-bounding-box-of-rotated-text) and [Three.js How to get position of a mesh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211627/three-js-how-to-get-position-of-a-mesh). I think they will help you.

Comment: `box3.setFromObject(Object3D)` looks good, curiously it isn't in the documentation.